# Echo check on which checkbox was checked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where i can edit the content, at this point i'm echo'ing the value of a checkbox into an input field but i rather keep the original checkbox's and show which one was checked.

```
     <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio11" class="radio" value="No Charge" />
            <span class="lbl">No Charge</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>



    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio7" class="radio" value="185.00"  />
            <span class="lbl">Networking: $185.00</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio8" class="radio" value="125.00"/>
            <span class="lbl">Mechanical: $125.00</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
```

If i echo the value its just going to show the value, how do i show which checkbox was checked instead?

```
value=<?php echo $radiochoice;?>>
```

Goal:

[image]

```
if ($radiochoice == "No Charge") {          
echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
echo '<label class="checkbox-inline">';    
echo '<input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio11" class="radio" value="No Charge" checked/>';
echo '<span class="lbl">No Charge</span>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<br>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
echo '<label class="checkbox-inline">';
echo '<input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio7" class="radio" value="185.00"  />';
echo '<span class="lbl">Networking: $185.00</span>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<br>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
echo '<label class="checkbox-inline">';
echo '<input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio8" class="radio" value="125.00"   />';
echo '<span class="lbl">Mechanical: $125.00</span>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<br>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
echo '<label class="checkbox-inline">';
echo '<input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio9" class="radio" value="59.00" />';
echo '<span class="lbl">Remote half: $59.00</span>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<br>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
echo '<label class="checkbox-inline">';
echo '<input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio10" class="radio" value="89.00"   />';
echo '<span class="lbl">Remote 1 HR: $89.00</span>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<br>';
echo '</div>';


} elseif ($answer == 185.00) {
```

ETC ETC ETC

Comment: why the mysql tag? there's no supportive code for it. And is that your full code? you using js/ajax or straight `<form>`? have you searched/tried something?

Comment: either you'r'e waiting for a magic answer or have left or ignoring my above comment. Please show some effort.

Comment: @Fred-ii- magic has already been provided :-)

Comment: @Dagon I have a more powerful tool; the "`?` wand `:`".

Comment: No ajax, i'm not good enough with ajax yet. Yes i tried to search. Give me the benefit of the doubt please.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i hate terney syntax, i cant even spell it.

Comment: @Dagon Bernie's Ternie's the way to go, IMHO... but that's just *"moi"*. Especially for radios/checkboxes.

Comment: Can you guys please elaborate

Comment: that's a really bloated solution, you dont need to repeat everything 3 times. you can still adapt mine to match your code (which we never got to see in the first place)

Comment: why is there `$radiochoice` and  `$answer` do you really have two variables for the same value?

Answer (score 1):

while not elegant on every input you can add

```
<input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio7" class="radio" value="185.00"  <?php if($_POST['radiochoice'] =='185.00'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>
```

alter the value accordingly, and it may be $_GET, depending on form action

Comment: there's a syntax error here. I closed your php code with ?> and the edit page doesnt even load

Comment: bad me, fixed @user1235709

Comment: Thank you but It doesnt show a check on the radio button

Comment: what's  the result of `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: update your question with: the new code, and the exact result from `print_r($_POST) `

Comment: i think i figured it out using my own code, i'll post shortly